# ¿Por qué el valor 00100 hace que este JSON no sea válido?

Tags: json

Yo produzco el siguiente JSON desde la llamada a una API:

```
{
    "breviario": {
        "info": {
            "fecha": "Martes 20 de febrero del 2018",
            "tiempo": "TIEMPO DE CUARESMA",
            "semana": "Semana I",
            "mensaje": "",
            "salterio": ""
        },
        "contenido": {
            "himno": "Amigo de los hombres, Jesucristo,~tú solo das sentido a nuestra historia,~y, con los ojos fijos al futuro,~la Iglesia vive fiel a tu memoria.§Este tiempo de ayuno te presenta~de nosotros la parte más oscura,~y tus manos clavadas al madero~nos devuelven tu paz y tu ternura.§A lo largo del día no nos dejes,~no nos falte la luz de tu mirada:~llena de amor los pasos que caminan~de este mundo a la luz de tu alborada. Amén.",
            "salmos": {
                "tipo": 00100,
                "s1": {
                    "orden": "1",
                    "antifona": "Han llegado los días de penitencia; expiemos nuestros pecados y salvaremos nuestras almas.",
                    "ref": "Salmo 118, 1-8",
                    "tema": "Himno a la revelación de la Ley",
                    "intro": "El amor de Dios consiste~en guardar sus mandamientos.~(1Jn 5, 3)",
                    "parte": "",
                    "salmo": "Dichoso el que, con vida intachable,_camina en la voluntad del Señor;_dichoso el que, guardando sus preceptos,_lo busca de todo corazón;_el que, sin cometer iniquidad,_anda por sus senderos.§Tú promulgas tus decretos_para que se observen exactamente._Ojalá esté firme mi camino,_para cumplir tus consignas;_entonces no sentiré vergüenza_al mirar tus mandatos.§Te alabaré con sincero corazón_cuando aprenda tus justos mandamientos._Quiero guardar tus leyes exactamente,_tú no me abandones."
                },

                "s2": {
                    "orden": "2",
                    "antifona": "«Por mi vida dice el Señor, no me complazco en la muerte del pecador, sino en que cambie de conducta y viva.»",
                    "ref": "Salmo 12",
                    "tema": "Súplica del justo en sus dificultades cotidianas",
                    "intro": "El Dios de la esperanza~os colme de todo gozo.~(Rm 15, 13)",
                    "parte": "",
                    "salmo": "¿Hasta cuándo, Señor, seguirás olvidándome?_Hasta cuándo me esconderás tu rostro?_¿Hasta cuándo he de estar preocupado,_con el corazón apenado todo el día?_¿Hasta cuándo va a triunfar mí enemigo?§Atiende y respóndeme, Señor, Dios mío;_da luz a mis ojos para que no me duerma en la muerte,_para que no diga mi enemigo: «Lo he vencido»,_ni se alegre, mi adversario de mi fracaso.§Porque yo confío en tu misericordia:_alegra mi corazón con tu auxilio,_y cantaré al Señor por el bien que me ha hecho."
                },

                "s3": {
                    "orden": "3",
                    "antifona": "Acreditémonos ante Dios por nuestra constancia en las tribulaciones, por nuestra sed de ser justos.",
                    "ref": "Salmo 13",
                    "tema": "Corrupción y necedad del impío",
                    "intro": "Donde abundó el pecado~sobreabundó la gracia.~(Rm 5, 20)",
                    "parte": "",
                    "salmo": "Dice el necio para sí:_«No hay Dios.»_Se han corrompido, cometiendo abominaciones,_no hay quien obre bien.§El Señor observa desde el cielo_a los hijos de Adán,_para ver si hay alguno sensato_que busque a Dios.§Todos se extravían,_igualmente obstinados,_no hay uno que obre bien,_ni uno solo.§Pero ¿no aprenderán los malhechores_que devoran a mi pueblo como pan_y no invocan al Señor?§Pues temblarán de espanto,_porque Dios está con los justos._Podéis burlaros de los planes del desvalido,_pero el Señor es su refugio.§¡Ojalá venga desde Sión la salvación de Israel!_Cuando el Señor cambie la suerte de su pueblo,_se alegrará Jacob y gozará Israel."
                }
            },

            "biblica": {
                "ref": "Jl, 2, 17",
                "texto": "Entre el atrio y el altar lloren los sacerdotes, ministros del Señor, y digan: «Perdona, Señor, a tu pueblo; no entregues tu heredad al oprobio, no la dominen las naciones.»",
                "responsorio": "Señor, crea en mí un corazón puro.|Renuévame por dentro con espíritu firme.",
                "codigo": "201"
            },

            "oracion": "Señor, mira a tu familia~y haz que nuestro espíritu brille junto a ti~con el deseo de poseerte,~al mortificarnos mediante la penitencia corporal.~Por nuestro Señor Jesucristo."
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que este valor: `"tipo": 00100,` me hace el JSON inválido. Por ejemplo, al validarlo en [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com), me da el siguiente error:

> Error: Parse error on line 13: ...os": {                  "tipo": 00100,                  "s1":
>   {
>   ----------------------^ Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Si quito los ceros delante, por ejemplo: `"tipo": 100,`, o si pongo: `"tipo": 0,` o lo encierro entre comillas: `"tipo": "00100",`... el error desaparece.

¿A qué se puede deber el error? Yo necesito el dato así, con todos sus dígitos, para hacer operaciones con él dentro de una App en Android. Podría enviarlo como cadena, pero me extraña este error y quisiera saber a qué se debe.

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361596/3045491) tienes una respuesta en inglés que dice que al empezar por 0 interpreta que es un numero en octal, y no es soportado por JSON. Varias respuestas sugieren que lo uses como `string` como tú intentaste. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b ignoraba ese dato. Agradecería una respuesta si es posible para dar la pregunta por resuelta. Gracias.

Comment: La puse como comentario porque es algo que acabo de buscar y desconozco si es totalemente así o hay algo más. Cualquiera es bienvenido de detallar más mi comentario en una respuesta :P

Comment: @lois6b sin embargo en Firebase yo tengo datos guardados con claves que empiezan por `0` tales como `01`, `02`, `03`... etc... y no tengo problemas. Se supone que Firebase maneja un JSON.

Comment: @A.Cedano y por eso no quise poner respuesta. Porque es algo que acabo de leer y no estoy seguro de qué limitaciones o en qué situaciones seria válido (buscaré sobre Firebase a ver que veo)

Comment: @lois6b en efecto, lo que tengo como `01, 02...`  en Firebase son **claves**, no valores. Si intento poner un valor como `01`, Firebase me lo convierte en una cadena, rodeándolo de comillas: `"01"`.

Comment: @A.Cedano aah vale. Gracias por la info ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Un número que comience con 0 y no seguido de `.`, no se considera decimal, sino octal. Por ejemplo:

```
var a = 012;   //Octal
var b = 12;    //Decimal
var c = 0.12;  //Decimal
```

La [especificacion](https://www.json.org/) dice: `"A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal and hexadecimal formats are not used."` Lo cual significa que un tipo numérico es muy parecido al uso que se hace en C o Java de este tipo de dato, **excepto que no se utilizan octales ni hexadecimales**.

Seguido hay una representación de cómo se puede componer el tipo *number*, donde se puede observar que *solo se permite comenzar con 0 si*:

- Le sigue un punto (.)
- Le sigue una e (minúscula o mayúscula) seguido de + (más) o - (menos) y un dígito.
- No le sigue nada (solo es un cero)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto, **JSON no soporta el tipo Octal**, por lo que deberías utilizar las comillas.

Si lo deseas, tienes más información en este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-0). (en inglés)

Comment: Gracias Ismael. ¿Sabes si eso viene indicado en alguna parte, en la especificación de JSON?

Comment: Sí, en la [especificacion](http://www.json.org/) dice: "A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal and hexadecimal formats are not used.". Lo cual significa que un tipo numérico es muy parecido al uso que se hace en C o Java de este tipo de dato, excepto que no se utilizan octales ni hexadecimales. Seguido hay una representación de cómo se puede componer el tipo **number**, donde se puede observar que solo se permite comenzar con 0 si es seguido a un punto (.), una e (minúscula o mayúscula) seguido de + (más) o - (menos) y un dígito, o nada.

Comment: Gracias. Creo que sería útil, cuando puedas, incorporar tu último comentario y el enlace, en la respuesta.

Comment: No hay de qué @A.Cedano. Ya lo he añadido. Espero que te haya servido.

Answer (score 3):

JSON no permite números que empiecen por 0 ya que. como dice @lois6b en su comentario, lo interpreta como octal.

Para solucionar el problema deberías ponerle las comillas, convirtiéndolo así en String, tal y como has probado y dicho que el error ya no aparece. De todas formas, dónde uses este JSON deberás tener en cuenta que el "tipo" es de tipo String y no un número.

Te dejo el [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361565/why-is-json-invalid-if-an-integer-begins-with-0/27361596#27361596) que hay en los comentarios y que te dirige a una respuesta en inglés.