# Campo ZEROFILL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Requiero que el id (**id_servicios**) de mi tabla `servicios` contenga el atributo `unsigned zerofill` de MySQL, hasta aqui, todo va bien. El problema surge cuando retorno los datos de la consulta con PHP, el **id_servicios** retorna un valor sin los ceros que requiero para tener un valor numérico de 11 caracteres.

**Imagen/Consulta**

[image: id_servicios]

**Consulta MySql**

```
SELECT svcs.id_servicios,
       svcs.llamada_servicio,
                    svcs.codigo_autorizacion_servicio,
                    svcs.fecha_servicio,
                    svcs.hora_servicio,
                    empr.id_empresa,
                    empr.nombre_empresa,
                    pnal.id_personal,
                    pnal.nombre_personal,
                    pnal.telefono_personal,
                    pnal.celular_personal,
                    svcs.id_tipo_servicio,
                    tser.nombre_tipo_servicio,
                    svcs.cantidad_movil,
                    svcs.direccion_origen_servicio,
                    corg.nombre_comuna_origen,
                    svcs.direccion_destino_servicio,
                    cdes.nombre_comuna_destino,
                    svcs.observacion_servicio,
                    svcs.fecha_generacion_servicio,
                    esrv.nombre_estado_servicio,
                    prna.numero_movil_persona
              FROM servicios svcs
              INNER JOIN empresa empr
              ON empr.id_empresa = svcs.id_convenio_servicio
              INNER JOIN personal pnal
              ON pnal.id_personal = svcs.id_personal_servicio
              INNER JOIN tipo_servicio tser
              ON tser.id_tipo_servicio = svcs.id_tipo_servicio
              INNER JOIN comuna_origen corg
              ON corg.id_comuna_origen = svcs.id_comuna_origen_servicio
              INNER JOIN comuna_destino cdes
              ON cdes.id_comuna_destino = svcs.id_comuna_destino_servicio
              INNER JOIN estado_servicio esrv
              ON esrv.id_estado_servicio = svcs.id_estado_servicio
              LEFT JOIN persona prna
              ON prna.id_persona = svcs.id_movil_servicio
              ORDER BY svcs.id_servicios DESC
```

**Código PHP**

```
<?php
 //Declaracion de cabeceras del sistema
 header("Context-type: application/json;");
 //Inclusion del archivo respectivo para la conexion con la BD
 require '../conexion.php';
 //Declaracion del array para codificar en formato JSON la variable mensaje
 $resultado = array();
 //Evaluamos si la conexion a la BD se realiza correctamente
 if ($mysqli)
 {
     //Objeto convertido a formato UTF8 para insertar caracteres especiales en la BD del sistema
     $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
     //Prepramos la consulta para INSERTAR datos en a BD a la tabla empresa
     $sql = "SELECT svcs.id_servicios,
                    svcs.llamada_servicio,
                    svcs.codigo_autorizacion_servicio,
                    svcs.fecha_servicio,
                    svcs.hora_servicio,
                    empr.id_empresa,
                    empr.nombre_empresa,
                    pnal.id_personal,
                    pnal.nombre_personal,
                    pnal.telefono_personal,
                    pnal.celular_personal,
                    svcs.id_tipo_servicio,
                    tser.nombre_tipo_servicio,
                    svcs.cantidad_movil,
                    svcs.direccion_origen_servicio,
                    corg.nombre_comuna_origen,
                    svcs.direccion_destino_servicio,
                    cdes.nombre_comuna_destino,
                    svcs.observacion_servicio,
                    svcs.fecha_generacion_servicio,
                    esrv.nombre_estado_servicio,
                    prna.numero_movil_persona
              FROM servicios svcs
              INNER JOIN empresa empr
              ON empr.id_empresa = svcs.id_convenio_servicio
              INNER JOIN personal pnal
              ON pnal.id_personal = svcs.id_personal_servicio
              INNER JOIN tipo_servicio tser
              ON tser.id_tipo_servicio = svcs.id_tipo_servicio
              INNER JOIN comuna_origen corg
              ON corg.id_comuna_origen = svcs.id_comuna_origen_servicio
              INNER JOIN comuna_destino cdes
              ON cdes.id_comuna_destino = svcs.id_comuna_destino_servicio
              INNER JOIN estado_servicio esrv
              ON esrv.id_estado_servicio = svcs.id_estado_servicio
              LEFT JOIN persona prna
              ON prna.id_persona = svcs.id_movil_servicio
              ORDER BY svcs.id_servicios DESC";
     $consultar_servicio = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
     if ($consultar_servicio->execute())
     {
        $result = $consultar_servicio->get_result();
        $data_area = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
          $data_area[] = $row;
        };
        echo json_encode($data_area);
     }
     else
     {
       $resultado['mensaje'] = "Ha ocurrido un error: " . $mysqli->error;
       echo json_encode($resultado);
     }
   }
   else
   {
       $resultado['mensaje'] = "No hay conexión a la BD";
   }
?>
```

**Imagen/JSON**

[image: JSON]

**Valor esperado en JSON/PHP**

A continuación muestro con este código que realmente el atributo retorna correctamente, pero por ser una forma de programacion insegura la descarto, por lo que ahora quiero ir mas a fondo del por que sucede esto?

```
<?php
  header("Context-type: application/json;");
  require '../conexion.php';
  $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
  $resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT svcs.id_servicios,
                 svcs.llamada_servicio,
                 svcs.codigo_autorizacion_servicio,
                 svcs.fecha_servicio,
                 TIME_FORMAT(svcs.hora_servicio,'%H:%i %p') AS hora_servicio,
                 svcs.fecha_final_servicio,
                 empr.id_empresa,
                 empr.nombre_empresa,
                 pnal.id_personal,
                 pnal.nombre_personal,
                 pnal.telefono_personal,
                 pnal.celular_personal,
                 svcs.id_tipo_servicio,
                 tser.nombre_tipo_servicio,
                 svcs.cantidad_movil,
                 svcs.direccion_origen_servicio,
                 corg.nombre_comuna_origen,
                 svcs.direccion_destino_servicio,
                 cdes.nombre_comuna_destino,
                 svcs.observacion_servicio,
                 svcs.fecha_generacion_servicio,
                 esrv.nombre_estado_servicio,
                 prna.numero_movil_persona
           FROM servicios svcs
           INNER JOIN empresa empr
           ON empr.id_empresa = svcs.id_convenio_servicio
           INNER JOIN personal pnal
           ON pnal.id_personal = svcs.id_personal_servicio
           INNER JOIN tipo_servicio tser
           ON tser.id_tipo_servicio = svcs.id_tipo_servicio
           INNER JOIN comuna_origen corg
           ON corg.id_comuna_origen = svcs.id_comuna_origen_servicio
           INNER JOIN comuna_destino cdes
           ON cdes.id_comuna_destino = svcs.id_comuna_destino_servicio
           INNER JOIN estado_servicio esrv
           ON esrv.id_estado_servicio = svcs.id_estado_servicio
           LEFT JOIN persona prna
           ON prna.id_persona = svcs.id_movil_servicio
           ORDER BY svcs.id_servicios DESC");

  $dataServicios = array();

  while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $dataServicios[] = $row;
  }

  echo json_encode($dataServicios);

?>
```

**Resultado**

`[{"id_servicios":"000000000007"},{"id_servicios":"000000000006"},{"id_servicios":"000000000005"},{"id_servicios":"000000000004"},{"id_servicios":"000000000003"},{"id_servicios":"000000000002"},{"id_servicios":"000000000001"}]`

> ¿Qué podría corregir para obtener el valor correcto de la consulta?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo completar con ceros el valor de una variable en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73996/c%c3%b3mo-completar-con-ceros-el-valor-de-una-variable-en-php) Si lo que quieres es poner valores con ceros a la izquierda en un JSON es imposible como números, tendrías que ponerlos como cadenas. Yo [tuve un problema parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139850/29967). En las respuestas se explica por qué es imposible.

Comment: Hola @Cedano de nuevo por aquí dandome la mano. Gracias, con respecto a la duplicidad de pregunta, no es lo mismo, dado que requiero es que desde mi BD pueda obtener un numero con 11 digitos que pueda ir aumentando, por ello el campo es (int 11 con atributo Zerofill). Y con respecto a tu problema, yo realmente en una version anterior de PHP habia usado el mismo atributo y el resultado del JSON era el esperado, como en el ejemplo `[{"id_persona":"00000030290"}]`

Comment: @A.Cedano Creo que es por la consulta preparada, cuando realizo una consulta sencilla e insegura proporciona los digitos esperados del identificador en formato JSON.  `$sql = $mysqli->query("Select * From consulta")`, despues declarando el array asociativo y por consiguiente da el resultado esperado, pero quedo con la duda realmente del por que (ejemplo en la pregunta)

Comment: @jecorrales, tu afirmación *"pero por ser una forma de programacion insegura la descarto"* no es del todo correcta. Usar `mysqli->query()` no es inseguro si no estás asignando valores concatenando variables a la consulta. En cuanto a la pregunta en sí. ¿Has probado a usar [`LPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)? Es probable que si mysqli detecta que el campo es entero, convierta el valor devuelto a dicho tipo, usando `LPAD` lo mantendrá como cadena de caracteres.

Comment: La segunda consulta no es insegura, si te funciona, quédate con ella. Por otro lado, el ZEROFILL es simplemente un entero unsigned que se muestra distinto, pero sigue siendo un entero y PHP debiera tratarlo como tal. Hay peticiones (RFC) [para deprecar este atributo](http://www.tocker.ca/2015/07/02/proposal-to-deprecate-mysql-integer-display-width-and-zerofill.html) porque la BBDD no debiera "opinar" sobre cómo se muestra un campo. Me extraña que la segunda consulta funcione sin castear el campo como string... yo lo que hubiera hecho es usar LPAD sobre la columna

Comment: Gracias por la correccion, @OscarGarcia...Probaré y les cuento!

Comment: Perdona, la marqué como duplicada al ver el título de la pregunta. Como dicen los compañeros, en estos casos lo mejor será usa `LPAD` en la consulta misma, porque PHP, al ser un campo `INT` hace un parse. Es como si hicieras: `$num= (int) 000001`, se va a mostrar al final solamente esto: `1`. Yo para evitar esto lo que hice fue declarar los campos como `CHAR (n)` donde `n` es el tamaño y eso sí, cuidar de que se introduzcan exactamente los dígitos requeridos. Dejarlo como `INT` te evita tener que hacer ese control, pero te obliga a usar `LPAD`, haciéndolo con `CHAR` te libera de `LPAD`.

Comment: Como siempre digo, No deben pasarle un problema de la vista a la base de datos. La base de datos guarda un numero. El problema de mostrarlos con ceros adelante es de la vista, a la DB no le importan. Salvo que esos ceros tengan un significado para el negocio, y en ese caso el campo deberia estar definido como algun tipo de string.